# create link (command shortcut) to script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am new to Ubuntu. I am trying to create a link to a script so that when I type `ideaiu` in the terminal, it opens `/home/bob/programming/libs/intellij/bin/` and runs `idea.sh` script from there.

I tried to put `export ideaiu="/home/bob/programming/libs/intellij/bin/idea.sh"` to `.bashrc`, but it has not helped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add it as an alias

```
alias ideaiu="/home/bob/programming/libs/intellij/bin/idea.sh"
```

export is for environmental variables and is used when you want the variable to be available to all shells.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158091/bash-defining-a-variable-with-or-without-export

Comment: Would this command have to be run whenever the computer is restarted, or the shell is closed? Is there a way to make the alias persistent?

Comment: Put the alias in ~/.bashrc . If you want the command to be on your path use `PATH=$PATH:/home/bob/programming/libs/intellij/bin/idea.sh`. If it is in your path, you will not need an alias. If you want the command to be available to all users put it in /usr/local/bin

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, you mean `PATH=$PATH:/home/bob/programming/libs/intellij/bin`; only directories make sense in PATH.

Comment: yes, can't edit that